# How to press cmd-\ on german keyboard layout

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'm using a german keyboard layout and wan't to use the `cmd-\`shortcut but I'm not sure how to press `\` as it is written by pressing `shift + alt + 7`.

The same question goes for `alt-cmd-[`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My friend is Greek and to type the black slash (or forward slash, I forget) he has to change input language! I guess this is the same issue you are experiencing?

So use something like Typinater or Presto which are keyboard mapping software for Mac.

Comment: Wow I hoped that I didn't have to change my keyboard layout to accomplish this keystroke. I'll wait some hours to see if someone got another solution to accomplish this, aka a secret combination ;-). If there is none, you'll get the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, it's probably best you do wait, I'm sure there are better answers but I think my post is a good last resort!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> can be typed using <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>RCtrl</kbd>-<kbd>ß</kbd>. Make sure that you press them in the correct order (<kbd>AltGr</kbd> first) and use the right control key. That's the only way it'd work.

Same goes for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>. You can reach it through <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>RCtrl</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd>

It may depend on the application. I tested them on Emacs and they work

Comment: `AltGr`? Does that really exist on a mac keyboard layout?

Comment: @Linus I'm using a Windows keyboard so I typed what I saw. Is there an equivalent on the Mac's? Perhaps the right Alt key?

Comment: good question, but I'm not aware of any difference between the left and right `alt` button.

Comment: @Linus [This post](http://www.experts123.com/q/where-is-the-altgr-key-on-my-mac-keyboard.html) states that it's either the right Option or the numeric pad Enter key

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows 11